# jQuery: How to uncheck random checkboxes in div after checking all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When `onClick` on link occurs, all checkboxes present in that div are checked.

```js
function initSelectAll() {
  $("form").find("a.selectAll").click(function() {
    var cb = $(this).closest("div").find("input[type=checkbox]");
    cb.not(":checked").click().length || cb.click();
    //........WANT TO UNCHECK checkboxes with class="file" where link  id is 'id="ninapaya"'; how to do that?......
    return false;
  });
}
initSelectAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      <div>
       Select
       <span class="kukapaya">(<a href="#" id="ninapaya" class="selectAll">alle</a>)</span>
        <br>
       <input type="checkbox"  class="document" name="check2">
    
      <input type="checkbox"  class="document" name="check2">
      
      <br>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="File">
  
    <input type="checkbox"  class="File">
    </div>
   

    </form>
```

Requirement: We should not check the checkboxes with `class="File"`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4d6zpay/

Comment: Use `:not` selector..

Answer (score 1):

It could be simplified using [`.prop`(`.prop( propertyName, function )`)](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and using [`:not` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```js
$("form").find("a.selectAll").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find("input[type='checkbox']:not('.File')").prop('checked', function() {
    return !this.checked;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    Select
    <span class="kukapaya">(<a href="#" id="ninapaya" class="selectAll">alle</a>)</span>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="document" name="check2">

    <input type="checkbox" class="document" name="check2">

    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="File">

    <input type="checkbox" class="File">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you make a separate line for the same with a check on id=ninapaya

Comment: Do you want to invoke a function only on the click of `id=ninapaya` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function initSelectAll() {
  $("form").find("a.selectAll").click(function() {
    var cb = $(this).closest("div").find("input[type=checkbox]");
    cb.not(":checked").not('.File').click().length || cb.click();
    return false;
  });
}
initSelectAll();
```

Also update in your jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/k4d6zpay/1/

Comment: Could you make a separate line for the same with a check on id=ninapaya

Answer (score 0):

```
function initSelectAll() {
  $("form").find("a.selectAll").click(function() {
    var cb = $(this).closest("div").find("input[type=checkbox]:not(.File)");
    cb.not(":checked").click().length || cb.click();
    //........WANT TO UNCHECK checkboxes with class="file" where link  id is 'id="ninapaya"'; 
    $(this).closest("div").find("input[type=checkbox][id='ninapaya'].File").prop('checked',false);
    return false;
  });
}
initSelectAll();
```

Comment: Could you make a separate line for the same with a check on id=ninapaya